# copied jquery-ajax - why 403? [CORS]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to simulate the function below. It is loaded from immowelt.de. But the js-file is located at https://media-static.immowelt.org/_scripts/mvc/bundles/homeDesktop.pack.js?3908a90b64b17c20b796248adf0296f8 .

Simulated Function:

```
        a.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: IwAG.Vars.acSource ? IwAG.Vars.acSource : j,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{ "inputText": "' + c.term + '", "limit": 150, "geoID": "' + h + '", "region": "' + g + '" }',
            success: function(c) {
                if (c.response && c.response != "")
                    b(a.map(c.response, function(a) {
                        return {
                            label: a.label,
                            fragment: a.fragment,
                            value: a.value,
                            district: a.indent == true,
                            fullLabel: a.fullLabel
                        }
                    }));
                else
                    b("")
            }
        })
```

Simulate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script><!-- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://media-static.immowelt.org/_scripts/mvc/bundles/mvcroot/search/GetSuggestionList",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{ "inputText": "' + "M" + '", "limit": 150, "geoID": "' + "108" + '", "region": "' + "0" + '" }',
                    success: function(c) {
                    window.alert("sometext");
                        if (c.response && c.response != ""){}               
                        else{};

                    }
                });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>click this:</p>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I always get an 403-error. I think the error is in the url. The other resolved variables should be right. Is the url wrong?

EDIT: I circumvent CORS through

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp"
```

Comment: The reason of 403 error is you are not sending headers. Since you are making a CORS request, you cannot send any custom headers unless server enables these header by adding Access-Control-Allow-Headers to the response.

Comment: Any more detail in the 403 error? Does it mention CORS?

Comment: Please show the full error message you get in the console and/or the network tab. It would show which URL is requested and if the 403 is caused by the server or by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting wrong URL:

The URL should be **https://www.immowelt.de/mvcroot/search/GetSuggestionList**

The major issue is CORS you can't run this at your own domain since at server end there is no header set to allow to all.

If you want to test below code go to https://www.immowelt.de/
and paste the below code into chrome console it is working fine.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.immowelt.de/mvcroot/search/GetSuggestionList",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{ "inputText": "' + "M" + '", "limit": 150, "geoID": "' + "108" + '", "region": "' + "0" + '" }',
        success: function(c) {
        window.alert("sometext");
            if (c.response && c.response != ""){}               
            else{};

        }
    });
```